# Почему ЯндексМетрика не видит мой заход на сайт с помощью HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser, httpwebrequest

В приложении `WinForms` создаю объект `WebBrowser`. С помощью свойства `Url` я могу переходить по ссылкам. Но аналогично я могу переходить с помощью `HttpWebRequest`

Пример кода здесь :

```
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36";

            //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("45.95.28.41:45876", true, null, credentials);
            //myRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            webBrowser.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

С помощью Url, Яндекс Метрика видит, что я захожу на сайт. А вот с помощью `HttpWebRequest` нет. Можете объяснить пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Возможно, надо что-то добавить или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что метрика работает через Javascript. А HttpWebRequest просто скачивает данные, никаких скриптов не исполняя.